# unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, jquery

```
string result="12334,23432,3453455";
```

I am getting this string through Ajax call but it gives me the following error:
"unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data"

When I remove comma's between strings it works fine .How to handle this?. I want to put value in textarea with comma's after the Ajax call

Comment: that's not JSON, it's a CSV.

Comment: I think you have the datatype in ajax settings as `json` and this is not a valid json. Try making it `text`

Comment: As mentioned already this is definitely not a JSON. A JSON would be an object or an array . So if you send an array rather than the comma seperated string it will automatically start working provided your return type is JSON

Comment: first make your datatype as text and still if the problem persists try appending \ before the commas, although it will work fine

Comment: @PSL: Please see that it is not a valid JSON. He Needs a Valid JSON in order to parse

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal Why do you think it needs to be JSON? Ajax call can retrieve other types as well like text/html etc and possibly here OP has json mentioned in the datatype...

Comment: That's because you need to specify what to get so that parsing the JSON object can be done by the Browser itself so that viewable in xhr logs as well

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal thats what i am saying, It seems like he is just passing just a string back, and mostpossible the datatype he might have mentioned as JSON, if you don't mention it then jquery will try to resolve it looking at the MIME type, so either remove it if it is already sepcified in the ajax or just specify text as dataType. It doesn't always needs to be in JSON format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever's outputting that isn't doing so in JSON format, but more like CSV.

A few options:

1. If you're able, fix the output method to correctly output JSON
2. Parse the string like a CSV
   e.g. `"12334,23432,3453455".split(',')`
3. Conform the output to JSON first, then parse
   e.g. `JSON.parse("["+"12334,23432,3453455"+"]")` (wrap with `[]`)
4. Specify `dataType:'text'` in your `$.ajax` call.

**Options 1-3** of the above would result in `[12334,23432,3453455]` as a javascript array of numbers, while **Option 4** will simply result in `"12334,23432,3453455"` as a string.

BTW, using `JSON.NET`, this is what it *should* result in:

```
// As an array:
Int32[] ary = new[]{ 12334, 23432, 3453455 };
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ary));
// [12334,23432,3453455]

// As a string:
String str = "12334,23432,3453455";
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(str));
// "12334,23432,3453455"
```

Comment: I am not sure about the second option as the problem in question does not mention the expected return type from server.
But the first one definitely & preferably correct but should be done on server end while sending the data accross

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: Indeed. I skimmed over the portion about placing the contents directly in to an input field. corrected, and thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your data has to be parsed by your JSON parser.

If your data is an `array`, your string should look like:

```
"[12334,23432,3453455]"
```

or should it be a`string`:

```
"\"12334,23432,3453455\""
```